# How to secure a web application you host but have no ability to modify

Tags: java, security, web

I have an web application (Java-html5/js) which runs on our servers that is accessed simply by its URL, no login options or checks. I have been asked to secure it, but I have no access to its source code and I have not managed to contact the developer behind it. It is widely being used on the company, so there is no option to shut it down. The other applications on the network require authentication, so I can use those credentials for this app as well, by redirecting him from a another page. But once he logins, how can I stop him from just accessing the actual unsecured url?

Comment: Cloudflare is your friend here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to change anything on this server, you may do the following:

- Install a proxy server with authentication on another machine - if there's not already one in the company
- restrict access to the app server to this proxy's IP address by putting it behind a firewall or changing routing rules

You need to go through the proxy to access and you need to authenticate. Way complicated but should work

Comment: The server running the app is managed by me, it is the application that is inaccessible. However, thank you for the guidelines, I will start working on this.